# VSTS git: How to get the "branch" from the remote repository?

Tags: git, github

In TFS:
We had a "master" branch called main. When we worked on features, we would branch the "master" into a "feature-branch". TFS would physically make a "copy" of the "master" branch in the working folder for the "feature-branch" that we can work on.

How does it work in VSTS git? I created a branch of the "master" called "feature-branch". I pulled the latest from the repository. How do I switch to the "feature-branch" from the "master" so I can work on the features? Is it as easy as just clicking "Branches" in the VSTS menu and then click the "feature-branch" in the "remote/origin" folder?

Answer (score 1):

If your origin is already set up, you just check it out.

```
git checkout feature-branch
```

To see all your branches

```
git branch -a
```

This will list them for you.  If you don't see your remote branch listed, then perform a fetch to get a new list of branches and tags from your remote

```
git fetch
```

If you want to create feature-branch locally, then you can do that, too.  This is my normal workflow.  To do this, you create the local branch, check it out and then you can push it to your remote.  Like this:

```
git checkout -b feature-branch
git push -u origin feature-branch
```

The first line created and branch and checks it out in one hit.  The second line pushed your new branch to the remote (named origin).